# Как применить результат анимации?

Tags: android

Всем привет! Такой вот вопрос: пусть я использую какую-либо анимацию, к примеру translate, в результате чего перемещаю объект, пусть кнопку. Как только анимация заканчивается, кнопка справедливо возвращается на свое место. Можно ли этого избежать как-либо, оставив кнопку на месте, в которое она прибыла в результате анимации?

Comment: А я сидел велосипедил... Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setFillAfter(true)
```